# CSS Overflow Marquee-Line and Floating Divs

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, html

Alright I am trying to get a row of social news feed to marquee across the screen. The problem I am running into is that when I add more than 6 items to display, it positions them on a new row. How would I go about getting them into one row and them using overflow:marquee-line to scroll them? Would I be better off using Javascript? If so do you know of any scripts?

Below is a picture of what I am working with:
[image: my issue]

This is the css code that I am working with.

```
.social-media-mashup {
display:block;
width:100%;
height:150px;
overflow:marquee-line;
/* margin: 1em 0; */
}

.smm-item {
width:273px;
height:130px;
float:left;
margin-right:6px;
}

.smm-item p {
overflow:hidden;
height:48px;
}

.smm-item p.entry-meta {
overflow:hidden;
height:16px;
}

#anchor {
width:100%;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}

#rt-bottom { 
width:100%;
}
```

And here is the HTML structure.

```
<div id="anchor">
<div id="rt-bottom">
<div class="rt-container">
<div class="rt-grid-12 rt-alpha rt-omega">
<div id="smm-widget-2" class="widget social-media-mashup rt-block">
<!-- Social Media Mashup plugin by Brave New Media -->
<div class="social-media-mashup icons-grey">
    <!-- Social Media Mashup cache is enabled. Duration: 60 minutes -->

    <div class="smm-item smm-twitter">
        <p>Content</p>

        <p class="entry-meta">Meta</p>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- End Social Media Mashup plugin -->
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any idea what to do?

Comment: Using `white-space:nowrap;` should prevent them from wrapping to a new row.

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to clarify. But there are two lines of entries one with 6 and the other with 4. I want one row of entries with a total of 10 that only shows 6 at a time, but scrolls.

Comment: Also, the `white-space:nowrap;` didn't act on the entries, only the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be:

```
overflow-style: marquee-line;
```

or that it's not supported by any browsers...

Theres this tutorial online by Nathan Rohler:

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/07/jquery-tutorial-building-a-jquery-scroller.html

That uses JQuery, You'd have to change it to fit your needs but maybe it's what you're looking for or you could just go find a plugin from JQuery...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jSnTG/

This was my attempt to change that tutorial into what you might want/need. Anyways Good Luck!